# Is there any equivalent of SAS merging in python?

Tags: python, merge, sas, concatenation

I am converting SAS codes to python but I could not find any equivalent of this joining method in Python ?

```
data have_a;
input ID amount_a;
datalines;
1 10
1 15
1 20
1 30
2 10
; 

data have_b;
   input ID amount_b;
   datalines;
1 12
1 14
2 12
2 14
;

data want;
  merge have_a(in=inA) have_b(in=inb);
  by id;
  if inA and inB;
run;
```

output;

```
ID  amount_a  amount_b
1   10  12
1   15  14
1   20  14
1   30  14
2   10  12
2   10  14
```

I have tried pd.concat and merge methods but I could not obtain a result above. Is there any direct method to do it in Python ?
I tried;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], 'A': [10, 15, 20, 30, 10]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': [12, 14, 11, 13]})
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

output;

```
 ID   A   ID     B
0   1  10  1.0  12.0
1   1  15  1.0  14.0
2   1  20  2.0  11.0
3   1  30  2.0  13.0
4   2  10  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Why would you want to replicate that type of merge?  What is the meaning for retaining values for variables from datasets that have run out of observations for the BY group?  Are you sure the original SAS program wasn't making a mistake to try to merge datasets with multiple datasets that have multiple observations for the same BY group?

Comment: It is kind  of a task I have to do. We don't have to keep the latest value for the retaining variables, It might be None as well. I am sure that SAS does not make any mistake. I also ask my colleagues who knows SAS well if there is a mistake here or not. Initially, I assumed that it is an inner join but I saw that it is not when I compare the output from SAS. It is a different join I have not seen so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to carry forward the last observation's value from the shorter dataset then just add a counter per group to each dataset (data frame) and include that variable in the join criteria.

[image]

But it will make the subsetting criteria harder (at least in SAS code) since you want to keep all records for groups that have any contributions from both inputs.  The IN= flags will not work directly since for the tail end of the group only one dataset will be contributing. You would have to retain the IN= flag variables' values from the first observation in the group.  Or you could filter based on whether the ID value is in the intersection of the distinct ID values from both datasets.

I will leave generating the actual python code to implement that logic to others.